# Check if Activity is Started with an Intent and If String Extra is passed in

Tags: android, android-intent

I want an activity to be started only from another Activity, so I am trying to check if this activity is started from that Activity. If not I want to disable the fields and pop up an alert. However no matter how I try to check for this, I get a NullPointerException

Here is my attempt.

```
Intent intent = this.getIntent();
        if (intent != null && intent.getStringExtra("uid").equals(null)) {
            showAlert();
            disableFields();
        } else {            
            mUID = getIntent().getStringExtra("uid");
        }
```

How can I refactor this to pass?

Here is my NPE
[image: Null Pointer Exception]

Comment: you call `.equals` on a null, what else could you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`intent.getStringExtra("uid").equals(null)` won't save you from a `NullPointerException`, since you'll be calling a method on a null reference if there's not extra with key "uid". You can use the [hasExtra()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#hasExtra(java.lang.String)) method to check whether that extra is passed with the `Intent`.

Answer (score 1):

IN case ur string is null edit ur if condition as

```
if(intent != null && intent.getStringExtra("uid")!=null)
```

Comment: Thanks, but that still crashes, maybe I should find a way to put this in a Try Catch block

Comment: Actually that works now, it was my disableFields() method that was crashing. The hasExtra() methods also works